What mitzvos did Moshe Rabbeinu want to fulfill in Eretz Yisrael?
The Gemara Sotah (14a) writes:

דָּרַשׁ רַבִּי שִׂמְלַאי: מִפְּנֵי מָה נִתְאַוָּה מֹשֶׁה רַבֵּינוּ
לִיכָּנֵס לְאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל? וְכִי לֶאֱכוֹל מִפִּרְיָהּ הוּא
צָרִיךְ?! אוֹ לִשְׂבּוֹעַ מִטּוּבָהּ הוּא צָרִיךְ?! אֶלָּא כָּךְ אָמַר
מֹשֶׁה: הַרְבֵּה מִצְוֹת נִצְטַוּוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְאֵין מִתְקַיְּימִין
אֶלָּא בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל. אֶכָּנֵס אֲנִי לָאָרֶץ כְּדֵי
שֶׁיִּתְקַיְּימוּ כּוּלָּן עַל יָדִי - Rabbi Simlai taught: Why did
Moshe Rabbeinu desire to enter Eretz Yisrael? Did he need to eat its
fruit or satisfy himself from its goodness? Rather, Moshe Rabbeinu
said: many mitzvos were commanded to Klal Yisrael, and some of them
can be fulfilled only in Eretz Yisrael, so I will enter the land to
fulfill all of them myself.

What were the specific mitzvos that Moshe Rabbeinu wanted to fulfill himself? Since he was a levi who does not have a portion of the land, many of the agricultural mitzvos would not apply to him.

People in Levite cities had areas for growing crops as Bemidbar 35 describes. in those areas they performed many agricultural mitzvos.

He could buy land. He could kill some Canaanites and smash their pillars. He could release a debt or a slave on shemita/yovel (d' orisa). He could establish a king. He could live in a levite city and allow in an accidental murderer.
